# Single or double dash between coauthors names?

Tags: spacing, citing, punctuation, hyphenation

Should I type:

```
In the foundational paper of Eells-Sampson (...)
```

or

```
In the foundational paper of Eells--Sampson (...)
```

So, single or double dash in the tex code between "Eells" and "Sampson" (the two co-authors)?

Sorry if the answer is somewhere on this site, I couldn't find it.

**EDIT**: According to Mico in the comments, I should not write either. How about when writing the "theorem of Eells-Sampson" or the "Euler-Lagrange equations"? Sorry if you find, like Mico, that this is a *completely different* question that has *absolutely nothing* to do with my original question.

Comment: Simple answer: Do *not* use either `Eells-Sampson` or `Eells--Sampson` in a citation callout. Instead, write something like `In the foundational paper of Eells and Sampson (1964), ..."`. There is the *Eells-Sampson theorem*, but the foundational paper was written by *two* persons with full names James Eells and Joseph Sampson, not by a single person whose surname was Eells-Sampson (or, for that matter, Eells--Sampson).

Comment: Ok, thank you. So what about when citing the Eells-Sampson theorem?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of your follow-up question. Did the Eells-Sampson theorem write itself? Is there an author called "Eells-Sampson Theorem"? One does *not* cite a given theorem; instead, one cites the publication or publications -- using "author-year" citation call-outs, if so desired or required -- that established what has become known as the theorem in question.

Comment: How about this: how do you write "Euler-Lagrange equations" in tex code?

Comment: I prefer [`Cauchy--Schwarz inequality`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) over `Cauchy-Schwarz inequality` (and as you can see from the previous link, so does Wikipedia). The [AMS Style Guide](http://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/index.html) recommends en-dashes (i.e. `--`) for situations like this (Appendix B, p. 125), but will allow single hyphens if used consistently. In the 'foundational paper' example you quoted in the question I would concur with Mico and write 'and'. ...

Comment: ... In any case I think technically this question is off-topic here (because it is not about TeX or LaTeX, but about conventions in mathematical typesetting) and might be more appropriate either at https://academia.stackexchange.com/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/. I wouldn't go as far as saying that you are asking completely different questions here, but the initial example and the tag `citing` combined may have suggested a different direction than you intended to ask about.